# Prevent new folders in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, source-control-explorer, tfs-security

I am unsure if this is possible, but my end goal is to prevent non-admins from creating folders directly under the Project. I still want to allow them to create folders underneath those folders though.

So for example:

```
ServerName
|
|---Project A
  |
  |--Folder A
    |
    |--Folder 1
    |--Folder 2
  |--Folder B
    |
    |--Folder 3
  |--Folder C
```

I want to prevent non-admins from creating folders on the level where the folders (A,B,C) exist. I want to allow them to create folders underneath them though (1,2,3). Is there a way to easily do that?

I haven't tried it yet but a possible option may be to prevent Check In permission at the Project Level but then at each folder level (A,B,C) allow check in. Is that the way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the permissions on the Project A folder, and for the Contributors group by default it will say Inherited Allow (for Check-In), change this to Not Set.  Then in each subfolder (Folder A/B/C) edit the permissions and change Contributors to Allow (instead of Not Set).

Comment: What about for the other groups those people may be in? Something like the 'Team' group?

Comment: The Team groups typically don't get granted explicit permissions in source control, instead they are added to the Contributor group and inherit their permissions from that group.  But you should still look through the various security groups you may have to see which ones you need to modify the permissions for, Contributors was just an example that is the most common scenario.